# How to break out of a while loop with a nested forEach loop?

Tags: java, spring

I have written a code which has a forEach loop and a while loop, and i am trying to make repeated requests until condition is satisfied using while loop. However, I am unable to break out of the while loop, as it gives the error "Break outside switch or loop". Also how can i go  to the next user iteration in the forEach loop.

My code:

```
while(count>0){

             usersClient.getUserUUIDList().forEach(user -> {
            try{
                LOG.info("USER STATUS for user {}",user.getId().toString());
                Optional<ExternalUserStatus> userStatus= adminClientFactory.newUssClient().getStatusForUser(orgId, Constants.IMP_ENTITLEMENT,user.getId().toString());
                System.out.println(userStatus.toString());
                if(userStatus.isPresent()&&(userStatus.get().getState()=="activated")){
                    //break;
                    //continue;
                }

                }
            catch(Exception ex){
                LOG.info("Exception caught while getting userStatus");
            }
        });
            count--;
             Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 *1);
        }
```

Comment: By using a traditional enhanced `for` loop instead of `forEach`.

Comment: You would have to throw an exception to effect a break. A labelled `break` to the outer loop from the lambda won't compile. To continue, just return from the lambda method immediately.

Comment: Why are you using `forEach()` here instead of a simple `for(User user : usersClient.getUserUUIDList())` in the first place, especially if it gives you trouble and no conceivable benefit (it's not even shorter or easier to read)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of break or continue (which won't work as they're in the lambda block), set count to zero:

```
count = 0;
```

If you need the value of count after you exit the loop, use a boolean as an exit condition:

```
   boolean done = false;
   while(count>0){
        for (UUID user : usersClient.getUserUUIDList()){
            try{
                LOG.info("USER STATUS for user {}",user.getId().toString());
                Optional<ExternalUserStatus> userStatus=adminClientFactory.newUssClient().getStatusForUser(orgId,Constants.IMP_ENTITLEMENT,user.getId().toString());
                System.out.println(userStatus.toString());
                done = (userStatus.isPresent() && (userStatus.get().getState()=="activated"))
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                LOG.info("Exception caught while getting userStatus");
            }
        });
        count--;
        if (done) break;
        Thread.sleep(1000*60*1);
    }
```

Comment: If `done` (or `count`) is a local variable then this isn't possible. Variables declared outside a lambda but used inside said lambda must be final or effectively final.

Comment: D'oh! Correct. Editing.

Comment: I should know better than to write answers in the middle of the night. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

From Bill Horvath's answer,

```
done = (userStatus.isPresent() && (userStatus.get().getState()=="activated"))
```

`done`  always takes the result of last `user` from `usersClient.getUserUUIDList()`

So better we can use one more break if activated.

> Add at the end of `for` loop

```
if(done)
    break;
```

Finally:

```
boolean done = false;
   while(count>0){
        for (UUID user : usersClient.getUserUUIDList()){
            try{
                LOG.info("USER STATUS for user {}",user.getId().toString());
                Optional<ExternalUserStatus> userStatus=adminClientFactory.newUssClient().getStatusForUser(orgId,Constants.IMP_ENTITLEMENT,user.getId().toString());
                System.out.println(userStatus.toString());
                done = (userStatus.isPresent() && (userStatus.get().getState()=="activated"))
                if(done) break;//Add this
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                LOG.info("Exception caught while getting userStatus");
            }
        });
        count--;
        if (done) break;
        Thread.sleep(1000*60*1);
    }
```